# Removing Background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background-removal

How would i delete the black background without harming darth vader in this image

Comment: SE isn't intended to be a tutorial board. You should make an [edit] showing your effort.  Also, it wouldn't hurt to request permission to use my picture.

Comment: I'm sure Darth Vader is a tough guy, and it is not harmed very easily.

Comment: Create a vector mask with the Pen Tool.  Don't know how? Use google to search for a tutorial - there are lots.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that there is no Darth Vader helmet outline. What makes this a good image is that the black background is fading into the mask as one, denoting the "oneness with the dark side". If you want to cut him out you will have to first draw in the rest of the helmet. The best would be to pick another picture, preferably one with a white background.

If you have one, use the pen tool in photoshop. Outline the whole thing, right-click and "Make selection", right-click and "invert selection" then hit the delete key.

Hope this helps